# Compute coefficient of generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I need to find the number of solutions of the equation $a + b + c + d = 19$ where $a,b,c,d \in ${$0,1,2,...,9$}.

I came up with $(1+z+z^2+...+z^9)^4$

But now I am kind of stuck and do not know how to compute $[z^{19}] (1+z+z^2+...+z^9)^4$

Comment: Do you know how to first compute $(1+z+z^2+...+z^9)^2$?

Comment: So I am getting the number of solutions are 660, would that be correct?

Comment: That is correct.